# Unable to use REPLACE function in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, replace, plsql

I was wondering what is the appropriate way to call the [REPLACE function described here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php), since I've created the statement below to test it but I'm getting an error:

```
DECLARE
 templateMessage3 VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
 templateMessage3 := 'Dear Mr./Madam FNAME';
  replace(templateMessage3, 'FNAME', 'Lilly');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(templateMessage3);
END;
/
```

Error:

```
PLS-00221: 'REPLACE' is not a procedure or is undefined
```

I am using Oracle 11g web interface.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions153.htm#SQLRF00697) is a function, not a procedure, so use the following syntax:

```
templateMessage3 := replace(templateMessage3, 'FNAME', 'Lilly');
```

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE is a sql function

So you'd need something like:

```
SELECT replace(:templateMessage3, 'FNAME', 'Lilly')
INTO templateMessage3
FROM dual;
```

(I don't have an Oracle install, so can't double check the syntax, but should be enough to get you started)

Comment: @PeterLang: works fine for me, although I'll agree that [my SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cb39c/2) is slightly different - but not in ways that I think make much difference. YMMV. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @FionaT and anyone else who needs an Oracle instance for one-shot playing around - you might want to get familiar with [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). When you first bring it up you'll be in MySQL - but if you click on the database name above the schema panel you can change the database to on of a myriad different types - just select Oracle 11g R2 and you'll be in business. There are some limitations, such as not being able to use DBMS_OUTPUT - but there are ways to work around that. It's a handy tool to have around. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis: Sorry if my comment was unclear. This solution works, but the slower (tried it) and more complex switch to SQL is not necessary.

Comment: @PeterLang: agreed that the switch to SQL is not needed. Not sure why people do this - perhaps required by older version of Oracle? But certainly not since 9i.

Comment: Agree with PeterLang that if there's no need for SQL then it's overcomplicating things to use it.  Answered the question from memory (haven't used Oracle for a couple of years) as it was Sunday evening and I thought the OP might not get much response!